# How do I solve Segmentation Fault (Core Dump) error in my CPU Scheduling Simulation program in C?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, scheduling, coredump, event-simulation

I am very new to C and am getting a Segmentation Error when trying to run the following code (which is a program that originally simulated an FCFS scheduling algorithm, but I had to modify to simulate SJF) and I am not sure how to solve it. It is for an assignment and I am to do the inputs: 4 for mean interarrival time, 1 for mean service time, 10000000 for length of simulation, and whatever integer for the seed. If I do only say, 1000 for the simulation length then it will work, but what is causing this error for 10000000? (the function puton_queue is where I added most of my code by the way, but if you require any additional information, feel free to ask). Thank you!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <values.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

/* simulation events */
#define ARRIVAL 0               /* arrival to queue */
#define COMPLETE 1      /* completion of service */
#define EOS 2           /* end of simulation */

/* programming constants */
#define FALSE 0
#define TRUE 1
#define DEBUG 0 /* set to 1 to turn debugging output on */

/* event list - which is a doubly linked list */
struct event_node{
        int ev_type;                    /* event type */
        long int ev_time;               /* time for event to occur */
        struct Custs *cust_index;       /* customer responsible for this event */
        struct event_node *forward;     /* forward link */
        struct event_node *backward;    /* backward link */
        } ;
struct event_node *top_event;    /* points to head of event list */
struct event_node *last_event;   /* points to end of event list */
/* customer nodes */
struct Custs{
        long int arrive_time;           /* arrival time of customer */
        long int CPU_time;              /* CPU burst time of customer */
        };
/* queue - simple linked list */
struct Queue {
        struct Custs *cust_index;       /* index of customer in the queue */
        struct Queue *next;             /* points to the next node in the queue */
        };

struct Queue_struct {
        struct Queue *q_head;     /* points to top of queue */
        struct Queue *q_last;     /* points to bottom of queue */
        int qlength;              /* length of queue */
        };

struct Queue_struct sjf;

/* statistics gathering variables */
float accum_resp_time;  /* accumulate customer response time */
float num_resp_time;    /* total number of custs in system */

/* input parameters */
float iarrive_time;     /* mean interarrival time */
float service_time;     /* mean service time */
long int sim_length;    /* length of simulation */

/* system variables */
long int clock;         /* simulation clock */
int busy;               /* flag indicating if server is busy */
unsigned seed;          /* seed for random num generator */

/* function declarations */
void arrive(struct event_node *ev_num);
void depart(struct event_node *ev_num);
void start_service(void);
void Gen_arrival(void);
void Gen_departure(struct Custs *index);
void Read_parms(void);
void Process_statistics(void);
void Initialize(void);
void Insert_event(int etype, long int etime, struct Custs *custind);
struct event_node *Remove_event(void);
void Puton_queue(struct Queue_struct *pqueue, struct Custs *pcust);
struct Custs *Takoff_queue(struct Queue_struct *pqueue);
long int expon(float time);

/*********************************************************************/
/* Name: main                                                   */
/* Description                                                  */
/*    This function performs the main control loop of the simulation.*/
/* It performs the following steps:                                     */
/*    1 - call routines to initialize global variables.                 */
/*    2 - schedules an end of simulation.                               */
/*    3 - generates the first arrival.                          */
/*    4 - processes the events on the event list until the end of       */
/*        simulation event i reached.                           */
/*    5 - frees event node after it has been processed.                 */
/*    6 - prints out the statistics when the simulation is finished. */
/*********************************************************************/
void main()
  {
  int not_done;
  struct event_node *event;
  /* initialization */
  Initialize();
  Read_parms();
  /* schedule an end of simulation */
  Insert_event(EOS, sim_length, NULL);
  /* generate first arrival */
  Gen_arrival();
  /* main loop to process the event list */
  not_done = TRUE;
  while(not_done)
    {
    /* get next event */
    event = Remove_event();
    /* update clock */
    clock = event->ev_time;
    /* process event type */
    switch (event->ev_type)
        {
                case ARRIVAL  : arrive(event);
                              break;
                case COMPLETE : depart(event);
                              break;
                case EOS      : Process_statistics();
                              not_done = FALSE;
                              break;
                default       : printf("***Error - invalid event type\n");
                }
        /* free event node by marking it unused */
        free(event);
        }
  }

/*********************************************************************/
/* Name: arrive                                                 */
/* Description                                                  */
/*    This function processes an arrival to the system.                 */
/*     It performs                                              */
/* the followiong steps:                                                */
/*    1 - generates the next arrival.                                   */
/*    2 - sets the system statistics.                                   */
/*    3 - puts the customer into the queue.                             */
/*    4 - if the server is not busy then calls start_service.           */
/**********************************************************************/
void arrive(struct event_node *ev_num)
  {
  struct Custs *index;
  /* generate the next arrival */
  Gen_arrival();
  /* set statistics gathering variable */
  index = ev_num->cust_index;
  index->arrive_time = clock;
  index->CPU_time = expon(service_time);
  /* put the customer n the queue */
  Puton_queue(&sjf, index);
  /* if server is not busy then start service */
  if(!busy)
         start_service();
  return;
  }

/**************************************************************/
/* Name: start_service                                        */
/* Description                                                */
/*    This function performs the following steps:             */
/*    1 - removes the first customer from the queue.          */
/*    2 - sets the server to busy.                            */
/*    3 - schedules a departure event.                        */
/**************************************************************/
void start_service(void)
  {
  struct Custs *index;
  /* remove the first customer from the queue */
  index = Takoff_queue(&sjf);
  /* set server to busy */
  busy = TRUE;
  /* schedule a departure event */
  Gen_departure(index);
  return;
  }

/********************************************************************/
/* Name: depart                                                     */
/* Description                                                      */
/*    This function processes a departure from the server event. It */
/* performs the following steps:                                    */
/*    1 - sets the server to idle.                                  */
/*    2 - accumulate response time statistics.                      */
/*    3 - remove the customer from the system.                      */
/*    4 - if the queue is not empty, then start service.            */
/********************************************************************/
void depart(struct event_node *ev_num)
  {
  struct Custs *index;
  long int temp;
  /* set server to idle */
  busy = FALSE;
  /* accumulate response time */
  index = ev_num->cust_index;
  temp = clock - index->arrive_time;
#if DEBUG
  printf(" Response time for customer is %d\n", temp);
#endif
  accum_resp_time += temp;  num_resp_time++;
  /* remove customer from the system */
  free(index);
 /* if queue is non-empty, start service */
  if(sjf.q_head != NULL)
         start_service();
  return;
  }

/*********************************************************************/
/* Name: Gen_arrival                                                 */
/* Description                                                       */
/*  This function will generate a new arrival. It has one parameter, */
/* stream, which is the random number generator stream to be used.It */
/* performs the following steps:                                     */
/*    1 - gets a new customer.                                       */
/*    2 - generates an exponential arrival time.                     */
/*    3 - inserts arrival event into the event list.                 */
/*********************************************************************/
void Gen_arrival(void)
  {
  long int time;
  struct Custs *index;
  /* get new customer */
  index = (struct Custs *) malloc(sizeof(struct Custs));
  /* generate exponential interarrival time */
  time = expon(iarrive_time);
#if DEBUG
  printf(" Interarrival time for customer is %d\n", time);
  printf(" Arrival time for customer is %d\n", clock + time);
#endif
  /* add the event to the list */
  Insert_event(ARRIVAL, clock+time, index);
  return;
  }

/*********************************************************************/
/* Name: Gen_departure                                          */
/* Description                                                  */
/*   This function generates a departure event from the server. It      */
/*   has two parameters: 1) stream - random number generator stream, */
/*   and 2) index - index of customer departing. The following  */
/*   steps are performed:                                            */
/*    1 - generate the service time.                                 */
/*    2 - insert the departure event into the event list.            */
/*********************************************************************/
void Gen_departure(struct Custs *index)
  {
  long int time;
  /* generate exponential service time */
  time = expon(service_time);
#if DEBUG
  printf(" Service time for customer is %d\n", time);
  printf(" Departure time for customer is %d\n", clock + time);
#endif
  /* add departure event to the event list */
  Insert_event(COMPLETE, time+clock, index);
  return;
  }

/**************************************************************/
/* Name: Read_parms                                           */
/* Description                                                */
/*    This function inputs the required simulation parameters.*/
/**************************************************************/
void Read_parms(void)
  {
  printf("   SIMULATION -- M/M/1 Queueing System\n");
  printf("      Input the following parameters:\n");
  printf("      mean interarrival time => ");
  scanf("%e", &iarrive_time);
  printf("      mean service time => ");
  scanf("%e", &service_time);
  printf("      length of simulation => ");
  scanf("%ld", &sim_length);
  printf("      seed for the random number generator => ");
  scanf("%d", &seed);
  /* initialize random number generator */
  srand(seed);
  printf(" Simulation time = %ld units\n", sim_length);
  printf(" Simulation begins...\n");
  }

/*********************************************************************/
/* Name: Process_statistics                                     */
/* Description                                                  */
/*  This function computes and prints the mean response time for the */
/*  customers in an M/M/1 system.                               */
/*********************************************************************/
void Process_statistics(void)
  {
  float mean_resp_time;
  /* compute mean response time */
  mean_resp_time = accum_resp_time / (float) (100.0 * num_resp_time);
  /* print out results */
  printf("...Simulation ends\n");
  printf(" Simulation results\n");
  printf(" mean response time ---------> %-6.3f\n", mean_resp_time);
  }

/*********************************************************************/
/* Name: Initialize                                             */
/* Description                                                  */
/*   This function initializes the event list, queue, customer list, */
/*   and global variables.                                           */
/*********************************************************************/
void Initialize(void)
  {
  /* initialize the event list */
  top_event = NULL;
  last_event = NULL;
  /* initialize the queue */
  sjf.q_head = NULL;
  sjf.q_last = NULL;
  /* initialize the global variables */
  clock = 0;
  busy = FALSE;
  accum_resp_time = 0;
  num_resp_time = 0;
  }

/*********************************************************************/
/* Name: Insert_event                                                   */
/* Description                                                          */
/*    This procedure will insert the simulation event into a doubly     */
/*    linked queue.  The parameters are as follows:                     */
/*     etype - type of event to be inserted.                            */
/*     etime - the time the event will occur.                        */
/*     custind - index of the customer associated with this event.      */
/* The following steps are performed:                                   */
/*     1 - get a free node and add the event information.               */
/*     2 - insert node into the proper place in the queue.              */
/*         2a - into an empty queue.                                    */
/*         2b - at the top of the queue.                                */
/*         2c - at the bottom of the queue.                             */
/*         2d - regular insertion (someplace in the middle).            */
/*********************************************************************/
void Insert_event(int etype, long int etime,struct Custs *custind)
  {
  int not_found;
  struct event_node *loc, *pos;
  loc = (struct event_node *) malloc(sizeof (struct event_node));
 /* add the information to the structure */
  loc->ev_type = etype;
  loc->ev_time = etime;
  loc->cust_index = custind;
  loc->forward = NULL;
  loc->backward = NULL;
 /* determine if the list is empty */
  if(top_event == NULL)
         {
         top_event = loc;
         last_event = loc;
         return;
         }
  /* see if it belongs on top */
   if(top_event->ev_time > etime)
         {
         top_event->backward = loc;
         loc->forward = top_event;
         top_event = loc;
         return;
         }
 /* see if it belongs at the bottom */
  if(last_event->ev_time <= etime)
         {
         last_event->forward = loc;
         loc->backward = last_event;
         last_event = loc;
         return;
         }
 /* it belongs somewhere in the middle so find its place */
  not_found = TRUE;
  pos = top_event;
  while(pos != NULL && not_found)
         {
        if(pos->ev_time > etime)
                not_found = FALSE;
         else
                pos = pos->forward;
         }
  /* check to see if we found something as we should have */
  if(not_found)
         {
         printf(" ***Error - problems in insert event routine***\n");
         return;
         }
  /* add node to appropriate place */
  loc->forward = pos;
  loc->backward = pos->backward;
  (pos->backward)->forward = loc;
  pos->backward = loc;
  return;
}

/*********************************************************************/
/* Name: Remove_event                                           */
/* Description                                                  */
/*    This function returns the next event from the head of the */
/* event list.  It checks for a special case where there is only        */
/* one event so the event list can be marked empty.                     */
/*********************************************************************/
struct event_node *Remove_event(void)
  {
  struct event_node *ev_ptr;
  /* check to see if event list is empty */
  if(last_event == NULL)
         {
         printf(" ***Error - Event list underflow***\n");
         return(NULL);
         }
  /* remove top element */
  ev_ptr = top_event;
  /* see if it was the only event - special case to mark empty */
  if(top_event == last_event)
         {
         top_event = NULL;
         last_event = NULL;
         return(ev_ptr);
         }
  /* event list has more than one element so just relink */
  top_event = top_event->forward;
  top_event->backward = NULL;
  ev_ptr->forward = NULL;
  return(ev_ptr);
  }

/*********************************************************************/
/* Name: Puton_queue                                            */
/* Description                                                          */
/*    This procedure inserts a customer at the end of the given         */
/* queue. The parameters are as follows:                        */
/*     pqueue - pointer to the queue.                                   */
/*     pcust - index of the customer to be inserted.                    */
/* The procedure performs the following steps:                          */
/*     1 - get a free node for the customer.                    */
/*     2 - insert the node at the end of the queue.              */
/*         2a - into an empty queue                             */
/*         2b - normal insertion                                */
/*********************************************************************/
void Puton_queue(struct Queue_struct *pqueue, struct Custs *pcust)
  {
  struct Queue *newnode;
  /* get an new node */
  newnode = (struct Queue *) malloc(sizeof(struct Queue));
  /* increase queue length by 1 */
  pqueue->qlength++;
  /* now loc is the index of a free node in queue */
  /* put information in the node */
  newnode->cust_index = pcust;
  newnode->next = NULL;
 /* check to see if the queue is initially empty */
  if(pqueue->q_last == NULL)
         {
         pqueue->q_head = newnode;
         pqueue->q_last = newnode;
         return;
         }

  /* if newnode's burst time is less than the first node's in queue, add to beginning of queue */
  if(newnode->cust_index->CPU_time < pqueue->q_head->cust_index->CPU_time){
      newnode->next = pqueue->q_head;
      pqueue->q_head = newnode;
      return;
  }

  /* if newnode's burst time is greater than the last node's in the queue, add to end of queue */
  if(newnode->cust_index->CPU_time >= pqueue->q_last->cust_index->CPU_time){
      pqueue->q_last->next = newnode;
      pqueue->q_last = newnode;
      return;
  }
  struct Queue *previous_node;
  previous_node = pqueue->q_head;
  bool searching = true;
  do{
      if(newnode->cust_index->CPU_time >= previous_node->next->cust_index->CPU_time){
          newnode->next = previous_node->next;
          previous_node->next = newnode;
          searching = false;
          return;
      }
      previous_node = previous_node->next;
  }while(searching);
  }

/*********************************************************************/
/* Name: Takoff_queue                                                   */
/* Description                                                          */
/*    This function returns the index into the customer array of        */
/* the head element of the given queue. The parameters are:             */
/*     pqueue -  pointer to the given queue.                            */
/* If the customer removed is the last remaining customer, the  */
/* queue is marked empty.                                       */
/*********************************************************************/
struct Custs *Takoff_queue(struct Queue_struct *pqueue)
  {
  struct Queue *loc;
  struct Custs *index;
  /* check if the queue is empty */
  if(pqueue->q_head == NULL)
         {
         printf(" ***Error - queue underflow***\n");
         return(NULL);
         }
  /* remove top element from queue */
  loc = pqueue->q_head;
  /* decrease queue length by 1 */
  pqueue->qlength--;
  /* get customer index */
  index = loc->cust_index;
 /* check if queue now empty and relink */
  if(pqueue->q_head == pqueue->q_last)
         {
         pqueue->q_last = NULL;
         pqueue->q_head = NULL;
         return(index);
         }
  /* otherwise just relink */
  pqueue->q_head = loc->next;
  free(loc);
  return(index);
  }

/*********************************************************************/
/* Name: expon                                                          */
/* Description                                                          */
/*    This function is used to generate an exponential variate given */
/* the mean time.                                                       */
/*********************************************************************/
long int expon(float time)
  {
  long int val;
  double temp;
  time = time * 100;
  temp = 1.0 - (rand()/ (float) RAND_MAX);
  val = ceil(-time * log((double) temp));
  return(val);
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Also please learn how to create a [mcve], with emphasis on the *minimal* part. Lastly also please learn how to use a debugger to catch crashes and locate when and where they happen in your code.

Comment: As for possible reasons, how much memory do you have? Do you have any checks to handle failed allocations (when `malloc` return a null pointer)?

Comment: I'm going to be honest, I have no clue. We were given the program already written and all I changed was the addition of everything after checking if the queue is empty in the puton_queue function (plus the addition of the CPU burst time variable). It works fine on the previous version using FCFS instead of SJF, so it has to be something I have done.

Comment: Update: Just checked my debugger and the fault occurs in line 481 which is my if statement in the do while loop in the puton_queue function: if(newnode->cust_index->CPU_time >= previous_node->next->cust_index->CPU_time){

Comment: @lunastellae Good start. Now use the debugger to look at which of those pointers are NULL or invalid. Then start tracing backwards to determine where and how it was set.

Comment: I have tried that and everything looks reasonable, so I am lost as to why it is giving me this error.

Comment: Then perhaps *uninitialized* pointers? Use something like [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org) to help you figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what is causing this error …?

In the line

```
      if(newnode->cust_index->CPU_time >= previous_node->next->cust_index->CPU_time){
```

where you try to sort the *newnode* into to queue according to the *CPU_time*, you just reach to far due to the misplaced `->next`; you rather have to check the *previous_node*'s *CPU_time*:

```
      if (newnode->cust_index->CPU_time >= previous_node->cust_index->CPU_time)
      {
```

Then, *this error* is gone.